# Problem after the installation of TensorFlow 2.11.0 version

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have just upgraded `tensorflow` to the 2.11.0 version but I am having issues while importing packages.

In particular, while importing the 'compat' and the 'keras' modules I got the following errors:

1. `import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf`

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat'`

2. `from tensorflow import keras`

`ImportError: cannot import name 'keras' from 'tensorflow' (unknown location)`

What can be the reason of these import errors? I never had them before but I had to upgrade to the 2.11.0

I have tried to uninstall and re-install but I always get the same issue.

I need the 2.11.0 since otherwise I have issues with the 'build' method for optimizers in the `tf.keras.optimizers` module

Comment: For me it was just after the installation of Tensorflow 2.15.0 from 2.12.0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TensorFlow is not installed in your system properly. Also do not use `compat.v2` while importing tensorflow, you can simply use `import tensorflow as tf` to import the tensorflow after installing.

Please follow the step by step instructions mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) as per your machine OS type (Windows, Linux or Mac) to install the TensorFlow. Let us know if the issue still persists.